# How can I use info sent using POST to display as a message?

Tags: node.js, express, post

[My goal is to get those errors to display on the front end, how might I go about doing this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY9oC.png)

Here is my code on the application level:

```
app.post('/register', 
[
    check('username').notEmpty(),
    check('password')
    .notEmpty()
    .custom((value,{req, loc, path}) => {
        if (value !== req.body.password2) {
            // throw error if passwords do not match
            throw new Error("Passwords don't match");
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }),
    check('email').isEmail(),
    check('email').notEmpty(),

], function (req,res ){
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.json({errors: errors.array()});
    }
    else{
        User.create({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password,
            email: req.body.email,
            name: req.body.name,
        })
        console.log(req.body.password, req.body.password2)
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned it, this question is related to your front end, not your back end. The way you can display these errors in your application depends on what language you are using in your front end. Are you using HTML, vanilla JavaScript, React, Vue, or something else? Depending on your answer, the way to handle the response from your Node service will be different. You might want to remove the `node.js`, `express`, and `post` tags from your question and re-tag it appropriately.

That being said, I can safely say that, given what's in the "Preview" tab of your request in the screenshot you shared, you will have to get the value of `msg` in the `errors` array of the response. You'll probably want to use some sort of JSON decoder/encoder for that purpose.

If you're using JavaScript, a possible way to handle these error messages might look something like this:

```js
const URL_OF_ENDPOINT = 'URL_OF_ENDPOINT'; // change this value

async function sendRequest(payload) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(URL_OF_ENDPOINT, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        });
        const json = await response.json(); // the JSON decoder
        if (json.errors && json.errors.length > 0) {
            const errorMessages = json.errors.map(error => error.msg); // loop through the array of errors and return the message
            console.error({ errorMessages });
            return { error: errorMessages }; // you can use 'error' to display a message on the page
        } else {
            console.log('No error message found.');
            return { json }; // you can use 'json' to display something that is not an error
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Oops! Something went wrong.', { error });
        return  { error }; // you can use 'error' to display a message on the page
    }
}

async function handleRequest() {
    const payload = { name: 'John', username: 'john', email: 'john@doe.com', password: '123', passwordConfirm: 'abc' };
    const parsedResponse = await sendRequest(payload);
    console.log({ parsedResponse }); // parsedResponse will have an 'error' property if there was a problem or a 'json' property if the request succeeded  
}

handleRequest();
```

I created a pen here where you can play with this code: https://codepen.io/yvesgurcan/pen/oNgvybY

If you want to know more about `fetch`, MDN has great documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

If you're wondering about `await` and `async`, there's also a page here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function.